# Why is it so hard to add a class to the <ul> tag in the sidebar widget?

Tags: functions, widgets, sidebar

I have created a sidebar:

```
function my_sidebar() {

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => 'Blog Sidebar',
            'id'            => 'blog-sidebar',
            'description'   => 'Sidebar For Blog Page',
            'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h5 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h5>'
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_sidebar');
```

I just added the "recent posts" widget and want to add a class to the `<ul>` tag but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in a simple way. I just want the `<ul>` tag to change to `<ul class="link-list">`

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and practical solution for you would be to add your custom class to the before_widget wrapper:

```
'before_widget' => '<div class="widget ul-link-list">'
```

Then use CSS rules accordingly:

```
.ul-link-list ul {
  /* Some CSS rules */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that results in `<div class="widget ul-link-list">` which is not what I want. I want to add a class to my ul list, not the div with class of 'widget'.

Comment: As i stated, this is the quickest workaround for you. Otherwhise you'll have to use javascript to dynamically add the CSS class to your ul element, or use some other wp hooks along with ob_start() and ob_get_clean() functions (you will probably also need regexp for this)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to modify markup normally via actions/filters because markup is hardcoded in Wordpress
\wp-includes\theme-compat\sidebar.php
[image]

So it's possible to change only via js, or php html output parsing

Comment: The files in `theme-compat/` are not used normally. You can completely ignore them, and yes, change the markup in your own sidebars.